# Refreshing "layer render order" widget

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

i made changes in the render order of my map canvas using a :

```
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setLayerSet(a)
```

"a" being a list of **QgsMapCanvasLayer**

My code is working as expected (i see result on map canvas) **but** the "layer render order" widget (dunno the right english name...) **is not refreshing** ...

How can i programmatically do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The canvas does not communicate its state back to the widget.

The layer order is managed by [QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge.html) which is only exposed as of (upcoming) QGIS 2.12 and in the nightlies since [now](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/70fe622661852db61f66f8b973d1991259338af2).

```
l = iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge()
l.setCustomLayerOrder(a) # a is a list of layer ids, make sure all the layers are in there
l.setHasCustomLayerOrder(True)
```